# When did I move to Andøy, Norway?

Tags: support, location

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does my location in stackoverflow profile change?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88217/why-does-my-location-in-stackoverflow-profile-change)

If you currently check my profile, it says my location is "Andøy, Norway".

I'm sure Andøy, Norway is a lovely place (løvely?) and have nothing against it, but I certainly didn't set that location myself, so I was wondering:  how did it randomly get updated?

Comment: Maybe someone found a Bobby Injection vulnerability and though this would be a fun way to tell SO?

Comment: Robert'); UPDATE Users SET Location='Andøy, Norway' WHERE UserName='LittleBobbyTables';--

Comment: We apologize for the fault in location. Those responsible [have been sacked](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NvIKL_pTZFE).

Comment: Aw, no fun, I was here first.  Just for that:  **A møøse bit my sister once**.

Comment: Looking at [the](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/88214/timeline) [timelines](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/88217/timeline), it looks like the *other* one is the dupe, not this one.

Comment: @John While the other one came later, the other one is also the one with the official Team answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems that some new functionality has been pushed to Meta Stack Overflow and Stack Overflow with regards to location entries. The rest of the Trilogy, and the Stack Exchange 2.0 sites, remain unaffected.

The location now has some form of auto-complete and validation. All previous entries have been auto-filled. For example, UK will expand to United Kingdom, and [NRW to North Rhine-Westphalia](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88217/why-does-my-location-in-stackoverflow-profile-change).

Apparently, whatever you had initially listed as your location expanded to Norway. And the number 6 will expand to Dublin, Ireland.

I imagine it might be related to some functionality with Careers, but we'll have to wait for an update from the dev team for the real answer. For now, though, this'll be the basic gist of what's going on (rather than why).

In fact the dev team have just spoken - [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88217/why-does-my-location-in-stackoverflow-profile-change/88220#88220)

Comment: [Nice!](http://i.imgur.com/cXIbP.png)

Comment: [Nicer!](http://i.imgur.com/5H4uD.png)

Comment: that makes sense.  I had "N/A" as my location before, so it's amusing to see the algorithm match "N/A" with "Andøy, Norway".

Comment: @Little: Wonderful! I can almost see why it mapped it that way, but it's hilarious.