# Location in profile was changed without edit or knowing

Tags: support, profile-page, location

The location on my profile page it has changed from **NRW** to **North Rhine-Westphalia**.

However, I did not edit that value or field myself. Did someone else change it?

Why did it change?

Comment: Related, maybe? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88214/when-did-i-move-to-andoy-norway Actually, noticing that this also has stuck me in Dublin... I think there's some strange things afoot.

Comment: There's an auto-completion feature in place if you re-enter your location...but I can't tell since when. Or why it suddenly would append your already entered location.

Comment: **Wow**... I just suddenly noticed that my profile claims I'm from Belgium.

Comment: Do I have to change my profile on **every** StackExchange site now?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We're doing a best-guess match on locations across the network in an effort to get more consistent location formats for all the users, for example mine would be "Winston-Salem, NC", "City, ST", or "Something, Ontario" for Canada, "London, United Kingdom".

To do this we needed to perform a backfill of locations across the network, but we can't do this instantaneously since we're hitting against Yahoo's API to do this (which would more than likely ban us for a massive hit like that).

It's unfortunate but we will get a few false positives in here...we've reduced that as much as possible and checked many of the matches to ensure the correct location's being returned...but some will slip through, and we apologize for that.  In the future this is done from your profile, rather than on the server-side, so whatever location you leave in that field after this we'll respect (but still recommend the match we found on the right **optionally**).

The process doing this is rolling through Stack Overflow right now (meta was done earlier) and will finish on the rest of the network tomorrow.

Comment: Geolocation by ip address is pretty unreliable.  On an unrelated matter I though you should know that there is a very large ocean in between Teresina, Brazil and where I'm actually located ;)

Comment: @user147272 - we're not using IP addresses at all :) we're going off what location the user entered already

Comment: Ah well, then geolocation by some random user input is even more unreliable :)

Comment: I'm curious, in the case of Grace Note, how did it get "Dublin" from "6"?

Comment: @John: "6" is a post code in Dublin:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Dublin_postal_districts

Comment: @Niall: Wow, that's some algorithm if it will match that!

Comment: It's an invasive algorithm, IMO.

Comment: @Nick Craver, where should I report the incorrect locations? Mine was Vilnius, Lithuania and got changed to Vilnius, Republic of Lithuania, as far as I see for users in other countries the type of government is not displayed, so this is probably a bug. I should note this happened on my stats.SE account.

Comment: @mpiktas - This was a *one time* cleanup of locations, if it's incorrect you can change it back and it'll stick.  I'm not sure exactly why "Republic of " is on specific countries and not others...it's Yahoo keeping track of official names here, for example: http://where.yahooapis.com/geocode?q=Vilnius,%20Lithuania

Comment: @Nick, ok, I've changed it back. Thanks for explanation.

Comment: @Niall C.: "L" is a letter in the [German alphabet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_alphabet). Thus, you must be in Vienna. \\(^_^)/

Comment: @RegDwight: I think you mean VieLLa.

Comment: @NiallC Alright, wisey, try this one on for size! My Gaming profile went from "Filgaia" to "Lower Salem, OH". We know the [how](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88306/where-is-the-documentation-for-the-correct-format-of-the-user-profiles-location), but what do you think the why is?

Comment: @Nick: sorry, but this wasn't very nice. Why? Well, because you guys rolled it out automatically and I now have to change it *manually* for more than a dozen connected accounts. Still, thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @Status: `Copy Profile to Related Accounts`

Comment: @SLaks: where do I find this? Didn't find it where I edit the profile.

Comment: @Status: In the Accounts tab.

Comment: @SLaks: thanks. This time it's too late already, but I'll keep it in mind.

Comment: Please don't *change* my profile without my permission, it's frightening.

Comment: It seems that my Douglas Adams quote maps to Scranton, PA. It is just possible that he would have found that funny.

Comment: I can only agree with @Stephen Swensen. I also think that it's an important communication issue to make such changes without informing users beforehand.

Comment: It also highlights the need for better profile management.  Manually correcting 10 or more was a real pita.

Comment: Might have made sense to sort by population, to avoid hilarious false-positives like selecting Brooklyn, AL (population: [0](http://www.zip-codes.com/zip-code/36429/zip-code-36429.asp)) over Brooklyn, NY (population: 2.5 million) when a user put in "Brooklyn" (as with my profile).

Comment: I fail to see why this was necessary

Comment: @Kyle - This was a decision by the team to clean up data formats that were all over the place, there are quite a few reasons we did this, for example many pages were inconsistent, or users wanting to query with data explorer to see how rep is distributed geographically, etc.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "many pages were inconsistent" - the location of the user is not present on any page except the profile, and it has no effect on the operation of the site. With regard to "users wanting to query with data explorer", you could have just as easily provided a modified users table with these corrections specifically for SEDE instead. Of course, what's done is done, (and I'm only complaining about this now because I it didn't affect me so I didn't know when it was done), but regardless modifying a user's profile without their knowledge or consent is bad.

Comment: @Kyle - That's not correct - for example, location is shown on `/users` list page as well, and the locations/formats being all over the place looked terrible beside many others there.

Comment: @Nick I still find about 1000 *strange* locations in the SO data dump, such as: "(c-with-templates)", "(the tiny red dot)", "/* no comments */", "/home/bedroom/bed", "3rd rock from the sun.", "A galaxy far, far away", .... From a geography-of-SO-researcher's perspective, I can't stress enough how inconvenient this is.

Comment: @BogdanVasilescu - As the answer says, this was a one-time mass cleanup, we don't *force* a location convention, we just helpfully suggest the closest match for those wanting to put an actual location.