# Who changed my profile location, and why?

Tags: bug

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does my location in stackoverflow profile change?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88217/why-does-my-location-in-stackoverflow-profile-change)

A few minutes ago my profile location changed from "West ByGod Virginia" to "Keokee, VA".
Is this some attempt to suppress something that might possibly maybe somehow offend someone?
I sure hope not.
Any idea how this happened?

Comment: [Why does my location in stackoverflow profile change?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88217/why-does-my-location-in-stackoverflow-profile-change)