# Location in profile changed

Tags: support, profile-page, location

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does my location in stackoverflow profile change?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88217/why-does-my-location-in-stackoverflow-profile-change)

A screenshot of my profile both on meta and on the main site – in fact, apparently on *any* site:

> [image: screenshot]

Now, I’m absolutely, positively, [110%](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UeOXsA8sp_E) sure that I have **never** entered “Delaware” as my location.

Belated April fools’?
Early Easter egg?
Insidious hack?

You tell me.

For the record, it *might* be related to [Why does my location in stackoverflow profile change?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/88217/1968) but I’m actually pretty sure that I’ve put something unambiguous and clear (like “Berlin, Germany”) into my profile field, and the change to “Delaware” must have occurred relatively recently.

Comment: It's a deal they've struck with the Delaware tourism board.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You put "DE" in your profile before, which translated to "Delaware, United States", could be simply because "Delaware" is first match of "DE"

This is a screen shot of your profile page in google cache

[image]

**Edit**: To confirm that, try this on console

```
$.post("http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/checklocation",{location:"DE"})
```

Which responses

```
{"friendlyname":"Delaware, United States","quality":20,"success":true}
```

Comment: Oooh. Now that’s absolutely possible. Now I just need to find a way to bulk edit my accounts.

Answer (score 2):

Your location was actually `DE` - U.S. postal code for Delaware. Of course Germany could also be possible (Deutschland, no?)

See: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/98444/, which is cached bi-monthly

Comment: Life is nice in Berlin, Delaware! It's hard to imagine that until only twenty years ago, it was split into four sectors, and a wall separated the city from a hostile hinterland.

Comment: @Pekka: Oh no, don't spread such rumours - no doubt, people will believe you!