# Do I have to change my location in every profile?

Tags: feature-request, location, profile-copying

I see that the locations were standardized ([Location in profile was changed without edit or knowing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88217/why-does-my-location-in-stackoverflow-profile-change)).  Mine is another where the default is wrong, although I am willing to use the suggested option.  Do I have to go change every profile or is there some way to change one and have it refresh all the others too?  All profiles are linked and use the same OpenID.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a "copy profile to related accounts" button on the accounts tab of your profile. Note that this obviously copies the *whole* profile, not just the location.