# Why do I have to change my display name just to update my website

Tags: support, display-names

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can my less than 3 character username be grandfathered in when I edit my profile?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92277/can-my-less-than-3-character-username-be-grandfathered-in-when-i-edit-my-profile)

I just logged into my account on stackoverflow and tried to update the website link.  I changed this one entry (and nothing else) and when I clicked "Save Profile" I was told:

```
Oops! There was a problem updating your profile:
    Display Name must be at least three characters
```

I would understand this being a problem if it had been the case when I originally signed up, but I don't understand why I need to change my display name from 'Al' (which it has been since I signed up) just because I want to update the website address.

Is there anything I can do about this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. At least three characters are now necessary for user names. When this was introduced (quite a while ago), existing names were allowed to stay *until the profile is updated*. If you want to change anything in your profile (e.g. your website), you also have to choose a display name that is legal under the new rules.

As of 14 September 2011, previously existing shorter display names [have been padded with dots](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106200/why-was-a-period-added-to-my-short-display-name/106213#106213).