# Where is the documentation for the correct format of the user profile's location field?

Tags: feature-request, support, profile-page, location, documentation

According to [When did I move to Andøy, Norway?](http://Meta.StackOverflow.Com/q/88214/) and [Why does my location in stackoverflow profile change?](http://Meta.StackOverflow.Com/q/88217/), there is now an effort to standardize on a canonical format for the `location` field in a user's profile. Entries which don't match that canonical format will get autocorrected.

Unfortunately, that autocorrection seems to be pretty much random. In my case, it autocorrected `Karlsruhe, Germany` to `Delaware`, which isn't even on the same side of the planet, let alone the same continent. When I re-entered `Karlsruhe, Germany`, it suggested `Ka, Democratic Republic of Congo` as the correct format. (Thankfully, that is just a suggestion and can be overriden.) In other cases, it seems to correct locations which contain the number `6` to `Dublin, Ireland`, randomly relocate people to Norway, or mangle the spelling.

Where is the documentation for what format is considered "correct" and what isn't, so I can make sure my entries don't get autocorrected? And shouldn't there be a link on the profile edit page to that format specification?

EDIT: Hmm … it appears that my memory is failing me and at least some of my profiles may have had `DE` as a location and not `Karlsruhe, Germany`. But it still doesn't make sense why that got corrected to `Delaware`. `DE` is the ISO 3166-1 ALPHA-2 code for Germany. The ISO 3166-2 code for Delaware is `US-DE`. If ISO 3166 isn't considered canonical, then what is?

Comment: In the algorithm's defense, my location entry consists *solely* of the number 6. And while I do remain curious about the algorithm, once you've edited your profile once, it will stick permanently without getting autocorrected (the autoset was a one-time event, basically)

Comment: +1 for your edit; here ISO looks like a good canonical source.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I thought It was using Google Geocode API, but actually It was using [Yahoo PlaceFinder](http://developer.yahoo.com/geo/placefinder/)

http://where.yahooapis.com/geocode?q=6 returns

> Dublin, Ireland,

http://where.yahooapis.com/geocode?q=DE returns

> [Delaware, United States](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88285/location-in-profile-changed)

http://where.yahooapis.com/geocode?q=NRW

> [North Rhine-Westphalia, Germany](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/88217/)

http://where.yahooapis.com/geocode?q=N/A

> [Andøy, Norway](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/88214/)

According to [Yahoo PlaceFinder Site](http://developer.yahoo.com/geo/placefinder/guide/index.html), they support following queries

- Single-line address: An address contained in a single field. The Web service parses the address data and return the best
  match.
- Multi-line address: An address contained in up to three boxes. The Web service combines the address data and then processes
  it like a single-line address query.
- Fully parsed address: An address with each component (street, city, etc.) is in a separate field.  The Web service does
  not parse the address, so it is less likely to
  interpret the address incorrectly, such as
  mistaking a street name for a city name.
- Point of Interest (POI), Area of Interest (AOI): Places not identified by mailing addresses, such as parks and monuments.
- Airport codes: The three-letter airport codes you may have seen printed on your luggage tags.
- Where On Earth ID (WOEID): A unique permanent identifier of a location.
- Coordinates: The latitude and longitude of a location.  Sometimes called reverse geocoding, this feature enables applications
  to get the address nearest to the specified coordinates.