# Under what circumstances could someone access my account?

Tags: support, profile-page, location

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does my location in stackoverflow profile change?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88217/why-does-my-location-in-stackoverflow-profile-change)

I'm not to knowledgeable when it comes to OpenID, but I was under the impression it is reliable and secure. Now today I find the location "Al Qibabat, Egypt" in my profile. This seems to be a free-form text field and I haven't entered that value myself. All logins happen via SSL, so I'm puzzled how this could have happened.

If there is a better direct "support channel" or issue tracker, please point me to it. Looking over the FAQ and searching I was unable to find anything like that. Only the meta sites.

Is this a bug or should I be seriously worried that someone took over one of my machines?

Note: I visit my profile regularly and that location wasn't set last night. So it must have happened within the last 12 or so hours, I reckon.

Comment: Yeah, Its Yahoo!

Comment: This is neither a bug, nor a matter of your account getting hacked. [There's some changes to the location system being done, and a *rolling update* was being applied to users across Stack Overflow and Meta stack Overflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88217/why-does-my-location-in-stackoverflow-profile-change). You apparently were just caught fairly late. You may breath a sigh of relief. ♪

Comment: @YOU: Yahoo? I'm not using Yahoo for OpenID or anything. Actually I don't have any Yahoo account :) ... thanks for the link about the duplicate. I'll try to mark my own question as duplicate.

Comment: @Grace Note: thanks. `*sigh*` :)

Comment: @STATUS: [It's indeed Yahoo](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88306/where-is-the-documentation-for-the-correct-format-of-the-user-profiles-location/88320#88320).

Comment: @Hendrik: yes, I noticed from the duplicate question. However, I'm nowhere near Egypt. In fact I would say that I'm at least 4000 km from Egypt. My former location said "Somewhere in the vicinity of Sol". Will this now be reset regularly or can I simply reset it back?

Comment: You can reset it once and it'll stick. This auto-set is one-time-only.

Comment: @Grace: thanks. Will change it back then.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]

A query to Yahoo! API

[http://where.yahooapis.com/geocode?q=Somewhere in the vicinity of Sol](http://where.yahooapis.com/geocode?q=Somewhere%20in%20the%20vicinity%20of%20Sol)

```
....
<city>Al Qibabat</city>
<state>Helwan</state>
<country>Egypt</country>
<countrycode>EG</countrycode>
...
```

Comment: LOL, okay. Thanks for pointing that out. Well, strictly speaking Egypt is somewhere in the vicinity of Sol, too ;) ... +1